# I swapped Pepe coin for eth on my trust wallet and can't find the eth in my wallet

Tags: etherscan

I swapped Pepe coin for eth on my trust wallet and can't find the eth in my wallet.

Transaction hx:
0xe3b68fd58b2b1ceca354b49babcca0ad7af938b0beba23d35b50eb9e7f6e80b9

Comment: you didn't swapped, you just approved. Your PEPE are still in your wallet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer 